# Derivative of log plot in python

Tags: python, numpy, derivative

We have the `x` and `y` values, and I am taking their log, by `logx = np.log10(x)` and `logy = np.log10(y)`. I am trying to compute the derivative of logy w.r.t logx, so dlogy/dlogx. I used to do this successfully using numpy gradient, more precisely

`derivy = np.gradient(logy,np.gradient(logx))`

but for some strange reason it doesn't seem to work anymore yielding the error: `"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "derivlog.py", line 79, in <module>
    grady = np.gradient(logy,np.gradient(logx))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 1598, in gradient
    raise ValueError("distances must be scalars")
ValueError: distances must be scalars"`

**Context:** When trying to detect power-laws, of the kind `y ~ x^t,` given the values of `y` as a function of `x,` one wants to exctract essentially the power `t,` so we take logs which gives `log y ~ t*log x` and then take the derivative in order to extract `t.`

Here's a minimal example for recreating the problem: `x=[  3.   4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  10.  11.]`

`y = [ 1.05654  1.44989  1.7939   2.19024  2.62387  3.01583  3.32106  3.51618
  3.68153]`

Are there other (more suited) methods in python for taking such numerical derivatives?

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] and the full Traceback?

Comment: `...for some strange reason it doesn't seem to work anymore...` - do you think numpy changed or do you think something is amiss with your data?

Comment: @wwii sure, I've just updated the post.

Comment: Taking the derivative would give you a point by point value for `t`. Usually you're interested in the overall behavior, and for that doing a linear fit would give you `t` directly.

Comment: My best guess is that `np.shape(x)` is a tuple with at least two elements. In other words, you are probably feeding a matrix or higher-rank tensor to the algorithm.

Comment: `np.gradient(np.log(y),np.gradient(np.log(x)))` works for me, Python 3.6.3, `np.__version__`
` '1.13.3'`

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel sure, taking the fit is fine only when there's one main governing power law describing the data. There are systems that undergo different behaviour at different timescales, so in order to capture that, the point by point approach is the way to go.

Comment: Not an answer, just a question about your expression: Why do you pass `np.gradient(logx)` as the second argument to `gradient`?  If you want to approximate `dlogy/dlogx`, the second argument should be just `logx`.

Comment: *"I used to do this successfully [...] but for some strange reason it doesn't seem to work anymore"* Which version of numpy are you using?  You can check with `import numpy; print(np.__version__)`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser oh wow it seems on a newer (`1.13.3`) numpy version it works!  The version that it didn't work on is `1.12.1.` Regarding the np.gradient(logx), good question, you're probably right (I'll think about it).

Comment: Looks like `gradient` had a bit of work done on it in 2017, see [this pull request](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/9408) and the issues and pull requests that it links to for more information.

Comment: I don't know.  You might not be the only one who runs into this, so an answer could be useful.  You are allowed (and even encouraged!) to answer your own questions (hint, hint).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thanks again, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the discussions in the comments the problem with `np.gradient` has been solved by updating the numpy package from version `1.12.1` to `1.13.3.` This update is specially relevant if you are also getting the `ValueError` `"distances must be scalars"` when using `gradient.` Thus, in order to extract the order of the power-law, computing `np.gradient(logy,logx)` remains a valid option of going about it.