# Implementing derivatives of logs of data in python

Tags: python, numpy, derivative, computation

We have two lists (vectors) of data, `y` and `x`, we can imagine `x` being time steps (0,1,2,...) and `y` some system property computed at value each value of `x.`
I'm interested in calculating the derivative of `log` of `y` with respect to `log` of `x,` and the question is how to perform such calculations in Python? 
We can start off by using `numpy` to calculate the logs: `logy = np.log(y)` and `logx = np.log(x).` Then what method do we use for the differentiation dlog(y)/dlog(x)?

One option that comes to mind is using `np.gradient()` in the following way:

`deriv = np.gradient(logy,np.gradient(logx)).`

- Is this a valid way of going about this calculation?
- Are there better (or equivalent) alternatives without using `np.gradient`?

Comment: You really want to compute the `log()` of a list of times?  That's unusual, I think.

Comment: @Alfe It may be uncommon but it has nothing to do with the actual question, you can imagine `x` to be any vector.

Comment: Wouldn't `np.gradient(logy, logx)` be what you are looking for?

Comment: @Alfe well I took the `np.gradient(logx)` as second argument there because we want the differences between the log values during the differentiation right?

Comment: `np.gradient([0,1,2,3,4,5], [0, 1, 2, 3.5, 4, 5])` → `array([1., 1., 0.8667, 1.6667, 1.6667, 1.])`  So I'd say `gradient` should receive the logs, and that's it.

Comment: @Alfie @user929304 You know what, I was wrong. It **is** defined as `gradient(y, dx) -> dy/dx`. Try with `y = x = np.random.random(10); print(np.gradient(y, np.gradient(x))); print(np.diff(y) / np.diff(x)); print(np.gradient(y, x))`. You expect an output of `np.ones(10).` Sorry, the documentation confused me! What you have is fine.

Comment: @FHTMitchell oh that's a relief ;) so it wasn't wrong, thanks for doing the check.

Comment: @user929304 Ok, I updated my answer for a final time. Short answer: It depends!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right after looking at the source of `np.gradient` [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L1510-L1848) and looking around you can see it changed in numpy version 1.14, hence why the docs change.

I have version 1.11. So I think that gradient is defined as `def gradient(y, x) -> dy/dx` if `isinstance(x, np.ndarray)` now but isn't in version `1.11`. Doing `np.gradient(y, np.array(...))` is actually, I think, undefined behaviour!

However, `np.gradient(y) / np.gradient(x)` works for all `numpy` versions. Use that!

Proof:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.sort(np.random.random(10000)) * 2 * np.pi
y = np.sin(x)
dy_dx = np.gradient(y) / np.gradient(x)
plt.plot(x, dy_dx)
plt.show()
```

Looks an awful lot like a `cos` wave

[image]

Comment: I have version `1.12`, actually the version issue has been a source of problem before for me, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48171283/derivative-of-log-plot-in-python

Comment: One problem is `np.gradient()` is requring the second argument (`dx`) we pass to be scalars, as it gives the error: `distances must be scalars.` So in fact I cannot get `np.gradient(logy,np.gradient(logx))` to work because it leads to that crash (given that we have taken log of our data, logx nor its gradient are integers). That's why in this post I was mainly interested in alternative methods, potentially using other libraries than numpy for these purposes.

Comment: Right, so use `np.gradient(np.log(y)) / np.gradient(np.log(x))`

Comment: Okay, is this really giving the same result as `np.gradient(logy,np.gradient(logx))` for you?

Comment: Yup. This prints `True`: `y = np.random.random(20); x = np.random.random(20); new_dy_dx = np.gradient(y, np.gradient(x)); old_dy_dx = np.gradient(y) / np.gradient(x); print(np.isclose(new_dy_dx, old_dy_dx).all())`

Comment: Great, thanks a bunch. And having deal to deal with logs of data doesn't necessarily invalidate the gradient approach for performing differentiations, does it?

Comment: So long as you're not producing complex numbers or infinity, no. You can always just rewrite d(ln y) / d(ln x) as du/dw; u = ln y, w = ln x.